# How to point a domain to a laravel installation folder on shared hosting

Tags: apache, laravel, laravel-5.3

I've installed Laravel 5.3 on shared hosting inside `public_html/NitsEditor` folder though SSH Terminal, the core domain of the hosting is something different i.e. "noeticitservices.com" and it has wordpress installed in it, so the laravel home page appears into `noeticitservices.com/NitsEditor/public/`

I've a domain named "nitseditor.com" I want to have `public/index.php` under this domain name.

I've configured the DNS of the domain to the IP address of my shared hosting and also added the domain through `cpanel`, while doing this I can see there is a folder named `public_html/nitseditor.com` is created.

Please guide me how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating domain through `cpanel` set path `public_html/NitsEditor/public/`